# Voice command classification - On Prem

Tags: audio-recognition

I want to do a voice command classification without using speech to text or cloud technologies. This is a followup of question [spoken-utterance-classification-on-ravdess-using-mfcc](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/80383/spoken-utterance-classification-on-ravdess-using-mfcc) which did not get much attention.

Using cloud speech to text is easy but dont want to stay offline. Current on prem speech to text solutions do not have decent performance.

Would anyone like to suggest some implementations which actually are working.

Comment: What systems have you tried, in what way were they insufficient?

Comment: I have tried CMU Sphinx and Mozilla DeepSpeech

Comment: Which language do you use? What was the performance problems you had? Did you do any fine tuning, for example to speaker or dialect/accent?

Comment: It was american and indian accent english. Speech to text results were not matching to what was spoken. No fine tuning was done to pretrained model

Comment: You can try Kaldi, wav2letter++, DeepSpeech2, EspNet. https://fosspost.org/open-source-speech-recognition-2020/
It is quite possible that you will get much better benefit if you finetune on a dataset with Indian accent english.